# Drawing circle on given path

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hi I have a given path and level of completion this path, and i want to draw a circle on place of given path relative to level of completion. I just want to know how to generate position on whole relative to whole path, I saw sth like that but just fore one quadratic curve

HTML

```
 <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="250"></canvas>
```

Js:

```
val.complet //thats vale i get to work
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(62.892882, 73.726092);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(64.235799, 70.400022, 69.829986, 69.388932, 72.484591, 70.364892);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(75.506155, 71.477482, 77.942145, 75.955172, 77.176994, 79.082152);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(76.505535, 81.826542, 71.422749, 93.237432, 69.552815, 97.754172);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(63.314496, 112.815130, 68.908683, 119.248650, 63.857127, 125.939820);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(62.041847, 128.344570, 52.883463, 130.397990, 46.742737, 132.689530);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(43.885134, 133.755280, 41.320318, 137.296050, 42.546121, 140.864160);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(44.451189, 146.415400, 50.076608, 145.423830, 52.969346, 144.502520);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(66.995806, 140.052150, 73.581567, 137.100860, 80.612364, 136.687050);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(90.961416, 136.081960, 96.442393, 138.763900, 107.427770, 141.028110);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(114.774780, 142.546700, 122.531690, 140.544040, 127.579330, 137.014970);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(128.223460, 136.566030, 135.882780, 131.647210, 137.971330, 130.663440);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(141.469170, 129.019940, 146.227930, 127.235880, 150.947660, 127.388140);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(158.376650, 127.630170, 164.712570, 127.852690, 171.813630, 128.204040);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(176.025870, 128.414840, 182.966880, 129.601610, 187.382100, 135.976560);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(190.633990, 140.668960, 193.241750, 148.597640, 188.201910, 156.479470);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(181.725450, 166.609920, 178.649250, 167.874760, 168.838920, 188.096580);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(166.637160, 192.632840, 160.594020, 193.733720, 149.187040, 190.911250);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(141.886870, 189.103780, 131.143540, 182.279880, 131.245030, 177.099500);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(131.088890, 176.631040, 131.330930, 172.360250, 139.786610, 169.272330);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(143.108780, 168.058230, 149.690630, 168.370540, 159.387740, 164.458900);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(166.539560, 161.577880, 167.117320, 157.080670, 166.516140, 153.922470);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(165.489430, 148.523470, 161.230360, 146.977550, 154.254200, 146.317810);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(144.514150, 145.396500, 140.782090, 145.314530, 131.307490, 146.060150);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(102.977400, 148.285340, 84.961230, 157.131410, 71.407134, 164.310550);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(68.982856, 165.598820, 68.147436, 163.408760, 66.777192, 161.027440);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(64.552010, 157.170450, 62.116020, 156.385780, 58.778245, 157.432000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(55.303838, 158.521180, 53.996053, 161.238240, 54.847089, 166.520120);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(57.310405, 181.791900, 59.078840, 190.798040, 61.487504, 203.239540);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(63.896166, 215.661530, 56.935638, 219.011000, 51.973869, 219.260860);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(30.819016, 220.322690, 26.427209, 217.441670, 19.494007, 209.634020);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.141238, 204.730810, 12.615459, 196.146280, 17.823168, 183.482260);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(32.973930, 146.645730, 44.693227, 118.475690, 59.516069, 81.654772);
    ctx.lineTo(62.892882, 73.726092);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white"
    ctx.stroke()
```

[enter image description here][1]

Goal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew7Ag.png

Comment: The code looks generated actually. No one hard coded this. Do you have the original source?

Comment: Thats exported path from SVG thats all

Comment: So you mean, you have no coding attempt?

Comment: I mean I litteraly dont know how to solve this problem, how to set position relative to given value of completion the track. Thats just track and want to place dot as car on it but I have just this one value

Comment: Perhaps you could include a visual of what you want? Like an image? A diagram that you edit to demonstrate desired output.

Comment: One think its giving x,y to % manually but that isnt the point

Comment: Its ok now? Sry, just first time posting, mby I need to work on it to